# Built in solution for validating an dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the following code to validate a dictionary (a) against another dictionary (check_against). Unfortunately my code isn't very readable so I was wondering if there is a faster/cleaner built in solution to achieve the same results. Maybe I just haven't googled the right keywords but I haven't found any discussion on what I would consider to be a fairly common task.

```
check_against = {
    'a' : str,
    'b' : {
        'c': int,
        'd': int,
    }
}

a = {
   'a' : 1,
   'c' : 1
}

def get_type_at_path(obj, chain):
    _key = chain.pop(0)
    if _key in obj:
        return key_exists(obj[_key], chain) if chain else type(obj[_key])

def root_to_leaf_paths(tree, cur=()):
    if isinstance(tree,dict):
        for n, s in tree.items():
            for path in root_to_leaf_paths(s, cur+(n,)):
                yield path
    else:
        yield [cur,tree]

for path,value_type in root_to_leaf_paths(check_against):
    a_value_type = get_type_at_path(a,list(path))
    if a_value_type == None:
        print(f"Missing key at path \"{list(path)}\"")
    elif not a_value_type == value_type:
        print(f"Value at path \"{list(path)}\" should be of type \"{value_type}\" but got {a_value_type}")
```

outputs

```
Value at path "['a']" should be of type "<class 'str'>" but got <class 'int'>
Missing key at path "['b', 'c']"
Missing key at path "['b', 'd']"
```

Comment: Do you mean determine if the dictionaries are equal, or only if A contains all elements of B (but perhaps more)? Or...? Define the goal.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked for, but jsonschema might be helpful? https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Goal is to check whether each key in 'check_against' is contained in 'a' and that its type of its value is equal to the one defined in 'check_against'

Comment: yes it works just not very elegant I also think it could be faster. I'm looking for a built in solution

Comment: Voting to close - Question belongs in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you're not opposed to using a third-party library, there are various options: e.g., http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/ or https://github.com/keleshev/schema.

Comment: My question isn't to review to code. It's whether there is a built in functionality to achieve the same results in python 3.6. I would prefer to have it built in as opposed to third party.

Comment: A bit off topic then.  Have you looked through the options in the standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your `root_to_leaf_paths()` function a bit to treat it as a general dict flattener. Flatten both the schema and the data. Then the comparison is trivial.

```
schema = {
    'a' : str,
    'b' : {
        'c': int,
        'd': int,
    }
}

data = {
   'a' : 1,
   'c' : 1
}

def flatten(obj, path = tuple()):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield from flatten(v, path + (k,))
    else:
        yield (path, obj)

fschema = dict(flatten(schema))
fdata = dict(flatten(data))

for path, exp in fschema.items():
    if path in fdata:
        got = type(fdata[path])
        if got is not exp:
            print(f'Incorrect type: path={path} got={got} exp={exp}')
    else:
        print(f'Missing key: path={path}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your `check_against` dictionary to only contain keys that are mapped to types, and then run against `a`:

```
check_against = {'a': <class 'str'>, 'b': {'c': <class 'int'>, 'd': <class 'int'>}}
a = {'a': 1, 'c': 1}
def flatten(d):
  _v = [[(a, b)] if not isinstance(b, dict) else flatten(b) for a, b in d.items()]
  return [i for b in _v for i in b]

new_check = dict(flatten(check_against))
for c, d in a.items():
  if not isinstance(d, new_check[c]):
    raise TypeError("At key '{}': expecting value of type '{}', got '{}'".format(c, new_check[c].__name__, type(d).__name__))
```

When running, the check successfully raises an error for an incorrect type:

```
TypeError: At key 'a': expecting value of type 'str', got 'int'
```

Edit: utilizing `a` as checking dictionary:

```
def check_values(d, check_dict = a):
  for a, b in d.items():
     if a in check_dict and not isinstance(check_dict[a], b):
        raise TypeError("At key '{}': expecting type '{}' but got '{}'".format(a, type(check_dict[a]).__name__, b.__name__))
     if isinstance(b, dict):
       check_values(b)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: At key 'a': expecting type 'int' but got 'str'
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in my case because I think your solution is doing the opposite (checking 'a' against 'check_against'). This means that when check_against is {'e': str, 'b': {'c': int, 'd': int}} it results in a key error. Still trying to understand the code though.

Comment: Actually I guess if there is a key error that is the same as my "Missing path X" output

Comment: @TheAschr Please see my recent edit.